# number of different observations in a column

Tags: r, filter, subset

How can I find how many different observations there are in a column?
For example in a column "species" with 3000 rows I want to find how many different species there are.

I read something about str(data) but I can't find it there.
Thank you in advance.
(I am new in R)

Comment: `length(unique(data$species))`

Comment: or dplyr::n_distinct(data$species)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` and `unique` to determine for example in the `iris` dataset how many unique species there are in the `Species` column. You can use the following code:

```
length(unique(iris$Species))
```

Output:

```
[1] 3
```

So this means there are 3 unique values in the species column.